# transfering variable value from BaseExpandableListAdapter class to new activity

Tags: android

I have the following code for ExtendableListAdapter class which extends to BaseExpandableListAdapter. 
I am trying to transfer the value of String variable "FullTrainsURL" to a new Activity. As you can see in code that URL-value for each child list-item is different and specific codes are appended by using OnClick() function.
I have tried

```
Intent i = new Intent(AdapterForStations.this, TestMain.class);

Bundle b = new Bundle();

b.putString("url", fullTrainsURL);

i.putExtras(b);

startActivity(i);    //Gives error at this line...
```

But the class from which i want to transfer the variable to new activity extends to "BaseExpandableListAdapter" other than "Activity". I think that is the reson that i can't use intent.putExtras(); method and i gets the error.

Can you please guide me how can i transfer "fullTrainsURL" variable to new activity by using OnClick() method.

:::::MY ACTUAL FILE CODE:::::

```
package com.multilayerexpandable.view;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckedTextView;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.javacodegeeks.android.xml.pull.R;
import com.javacodegeeks.android.xml.pull.XmlParsingStationsData;
import com.javacodegeeks.android.xml.pull.model.Station;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public class AdapterForStations extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private static final String baseUrlForTrains = "http://cloud.tfl.gov.uk/TrackerNet/PredictionDetailed/";

XmlParsingStationsData parsingStations = new XmlParsingStationsData();
MainStationsActivity stationActivity = new MainStationsActivity();
LinkedList<Station> stationsList = new LinkedList<Station>();

public ArrayList<String> groupItem, tempChild;
public ArrayList<Object> Childtem = new ArrayList<Object>();
public LayoutInflater minflater;
public Activity activity;
private final String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();



public AdapterForStations(ArrayList<String> grList, ArrayList<Object> childItem) {
    groupItem = grList;
    this.Childtem = childItem;
}

public void setInflater(LayoutInflater mInflater, Activity act) {
    this.minflater = mInflater;
    activity = act;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
    boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    tempChild = (ArrayList<String>) Childtem.get(groupPosition);

    Log.d(TAG, "::::::::::::::::::::DATA:::::::::::::::::::\n" + "<<<<<<" + tempChild.get(childPosition) + ">>>>>>\n");

    TextView text = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = minflater.inflate(R.layout.childrow, null);
    }
    text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    text.setText(tempChild.get(childPosition));
    convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            StringBuilder trainsUrl = new StringBuilder(baseUrlForTrains);
            String fullTrainsURL = "";

                if(groupItem.get(groupPosition).equals("BAKERLOO LINE")){
                String stationCode = tempChild.get(childPosition).substring(tempChild.get(childPosition).length()-4, tempChild.get(childPosition).length()-1);
                trainsUrl.append("B/").append(stationCode);
                fullTrainsURL = trainsUrl.toString();

                Intent i = new Intent(AdapterForStations.this, TestMain.class);
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putString("url", fullTrainsURL);
                i.putExtras(b);
                startActivity(i);


            } else if(groupItem.get(groupPosition).equals("CENTRAL LINE")){
                String stationCode = tempChild.get(childPosition).substring(tempChild.get(childPosition).length()-4, tempChild.get(childPosition).length()-1);
                trainsUrl.append("C/").append(stationCode);
                fullTrainsURL = trainsUrl.toString();


            } else if(groupItem.get(groupPosition).equals("CIRCLE LINE")){
                String stationCode = tempChild.get(childPosition).substring(tempChild.get(childPosition).length()-4, tempChild.get(childPosition).length()-1);
                trainsUrl.append("H/").append(stationCode);
                fullTrainsURL = trainsUrl.toString();


            }

            Toast.makeText(activity, fullTrainsURL,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

    });
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return ((ArrayList<String>) Childtem.get(groupPosition)).size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return groupItem.size();
}

@Override
public void onGroupCollapsed(int groupPosition) {
    super.onGroupCollapsed(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public void onGroupExpanded(int groupPosition) {
    super.onGroupExpanded(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = minflater.inflate(R.layout.grouprow, null);
    }
    ((CheckedTextView) convertView).setText(groupItem.get(groupPosition));
    ((CheckedTextView) convertView).setChecked(isExpanded);
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return false;
}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`startActivity()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivity%28android.content.Intent%29) is a member of the Context class, try something like this:

```
Context context = v.getContext();
Intent i = new Intent(context, TestMain.class);
i.putExtra("url", fullTrainsURL);
context.startActivity(i);
```

Also you don't need to create a second Bundle, just add the String directly into the Intent's built-in Bundle.

Comment: Thanks, it worked in my ExtendableListAdapter Class in OnClick() method. i have used the following lines of code in my "TestMain" Class to get the value of variable:                                                 // Recieving data came from AdapterForStations class
      Intent newIntent = getIntent();
            String fullURL =     newIntent.getExtras().getString("url");

Answer (score 1):

Errrr... adapters are not Activities, they're meant to hold data and provide a view to AdapterViews (e.g. ListView). They adapt the data to a View. You need to create an activity that has a listview that uses your AdapterForStations and start that instead.

The Constructor of an Adapter should generally include all of the data that it needs.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by other answers: the adapter is only meant to bind data against views in an efficient way. As such, it's not really meant to contain any code for user interaction.

Luckily, your adapter should be set to an `ExpandableListActivity` or `ExpandableListView` and those do provide the means for easily responding to e.g. user clicks on items. Refer to the following relevant methods:

- [`onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ExpandableListActivity.html#onChildClick%28android.widget.ExpandableListView,%20android.view.View,%20int,%20int,%20long%29)
- [`setOnChildClickListener(ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener onChildClickListener)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html#setOnChildClickListener%28android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener%29)

(you can also listen for clicks on 'group' items, if you'd need to)

Using one of the above mentioned approaches, you can copy-paste most of what's currently in the `OnClickListener` in your adapter. You'll probably only need to change where you get your data object from.

Since you'll set up the listener in your `Activity` or `Fragment` that contains the `ExpandableListView` (and both extend `Context`), you can call `startActivity(...)` right away.